# AdWords API CampaignService.Query() returns INVALID_PREDICATE_FIELD_NAME for valid fields

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm having trouble getting a simple [AWQL](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/awql) syntax to work with the AdWords API CampaignService.  I'm trying to gather a list of all CampaignIds that have greater than 10 impressions for a date range:

```
campaignService = authorizedClient.GetService('CampaignService', version='v201406')

awql = "SELECT CampaignId WHERE Impressions > 10 DURING 20150120,20150223"

results = campaignService.query(awql)
```

The above syntax gives the following error:

```
Server raised fault: '[SelectorError.INVALID_PREDICATE_FIELD_NAME @ query; trigger:'Impressions'; errorDetails:Impressions] Original AdsAPI trace for debugging [
com.google.ads.api.services.common.error.ApiException: [SelectorError.INVALID_PREDICATE_FIELD_NAME @ query; trigger:'Impressions'; errorDetails:Impressions]
```

Whenever I adjust the Awql syntax as follows, I get a successful result:

```
campaignService = authorizedClient.GetService('CampaignService', version='v201406')

# Works
awql = "SELECT CampaignId"
results = campaignService.query(awql)

# Works
awql = "SELECT CampaignId DURING 20150120,20150223"
results = campaignService.query(awql)

# Doesn't Work
awql = "SELECT CampaignId WHERE Impressions >10 DURING 20150120,20150223"
results = campaignService.query(awql)
```

I've tried using `impression`, `Impression`, `impressions` and none of those work either.  I can confirm via the AdWords UI that there are campaigns on this account that have impressions during this time period.

Why won't the CampaignService let me query with Impressions as a `WHERE` filter?

Edit: I found a list of [filterable fields](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201409/MutateJobService.Campaign) here for campaigns, but in the documentation example [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/awql) it shows them using Impressions?

```
CampaignPage p = campaignService.query("SELECT CampaignId,CampaignName
                WHERE Ctr > 0.05 AND Impressions < 100
                DURING 20120201,20120228 ORDER BY CampaignName DESC LIMIT 0,50");
```

Comment: Won't let me add [google-adwords-api] tag for some reason

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question but maybe it could be easier to test your queries with https://www.awql.me. I know there is some interactive help with the errors in the queries

Comment: I don't think the AWQL syntax itself is the issue.  On the AWQL documentation page, they give an identical example using Impressions with CampaignService.

Comment: There is no 'FROM' clause in your query. When I write AWQL query, I wrote for example select
 Date, Clicks
from ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
during LAST_7_DAYS . I think you must specify on which table you want to query.

Comment: Nope. The `FROM <REPORT NAME>` is only needed when you do ad hoc AWQL report requests.  The API selectors accept AWQL as service calls, but only when you exclude the `FROM`.  It's explained in the documentation I link to in line 1 of the question.

Comment: Not all comparison operators are available for all fields. See this question [about selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060687/not-able-to-add-predicate-to-selector-with-google-adwords-api).